Correct authentication for accessing sharepoint REST API
The problem I have is that I am unable to access the sharepoint REST Api with 401 : [{"error":{"code":"accessDenied","message":"There has been an error authenticating the request."}}] and I cannot figure out why.
The authentication steps I tried were:
Authentication by secret using MSAL4J:
IClientCredential clientCredential = ClientCredentialFactory.createFromSecret(clientSecret);
ConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientApplication.builder(clientId, clientCredential).authority("https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantId").build();
ClientCredentialParameters parameters = ClientCredentialParameters.builder(Collections.singleton("https://" + tenantName + ".sharepoint.com/.default")).build();
IAuthenticationResult result = app.acquireToken(parameters).join();

Authentication by certificate using MSAL4J:
IClientCredential clientCredential;
try (FileInputStream certStream = new FileInputStream(certPath)) {
    clientCredential = ClientCredentialFactory.createFromCertificate(certStream, certPassword);
}
ConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientApplication.builder(clientId, clientCredential).authority("https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantId").build();
ClientCredentialParameters parameters = ClientCredentialParameters.builder(Collections.singleton("https://" + tenantName + ".sharepoint.com/.default")).build();
IAuthenticationResult result = app.acquireToken(parameters).join();

Authentication by secret using  REST API:
var headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

MultiValueMap<String, String> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
body.add("client_id", clientID);
body.add("scope", "https://" + tenantName + ".sharepoint.com/.default");
body.add("client_secret", clientSecret);
body.add("grant_type", "client_credentials");

var entity = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);

ResponseEntity<Map> response = restTemplate.exchange("https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantId + "/oauth2/token", HttpMethod.POST, entity, Map.class);

In all cases I get the access token but then the GET to 'https://" + tenantName + ".sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/web/title' fails. I am using this request:
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setBearerAuth(accessToken);
headers.set("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);

The app is registered, all permissions are granted for app-only and granted by administrator.

Access denied is the expected result if you are using a registered Entra ID application with a client secret. Due to security reinforcement, only certificate will work.

FAQ: Can I use other means besides certificates for realizing app-only access for my Azure AD app?
No, all other options are blocked by SharePoint Online and will result
in an Access Denied message.

Source: Granting access via Azure AD App-Only
Try to generate a new certificate for your application with application permissions Sites.FullControl.All and use it to connect to SharePoint:
$password = (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText 'myprivatekeypassword' -Force)
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "contoso.sharepoint.com" -ClientId 6c5c98c7-e05a-4a0f-bcfa-0cfc65aa1f28 -CertificatePath 'c:\mycertificate.pfx' -CertificatePassword $password  -Tenant 'contoso.onmicrosoft.com'

Reference: Connect-PnPOnline

